# Heap corruption? In MY dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

```
void longcatislong(int* cat, int &size, int &looong)
{
    int* longcat = new int[looong*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
        longcat[i] = cat[i];
    delete [] cat;
    cat = longcat;
    looong = looong * 2;
}
```

Soup guys.  I'm /r/equesting some help with this problem I have with my code.  Apparently something in my C++ code caused a heap corruption error and that something is `delete[] cat`.  cat is a dynamic array of ints that was created with the new operator and a pointer.  Why, then is it that when I use the array delete the whole program decides to get crushed under a steamroller and say I got heap corruption.  I'm 12 and what is this?

Comment: -1 Please keep the 4chan on 4chan. (And if you're going to try anyway, at least don't be a new---...)

Comment: Don't you know the rules 1 and 2?

Comment: That are basically the rules for using C++ - every line IS a steamroller.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `cat` pointer by value so whatever changes you do inside the function is not reflected outside. You need to pass the pointer by reference like `int*& cat`.

Comment: You are still getting heap corruption? then can you post the code which calls this function.

Comment: If you are deleting cat once then dont you have to allocate memory before copying some value to it.

Comment: I don't see why that would be true. cat is simply an address that points to data. If he does a delete[] cat it should be reflected outside the function.

Comment: @Sagekilla: I mean `cat = longcat;` will not be reflected outside and the pointer `cat` will be pointing to invalid memory location.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is *not* being returned to the caller of this function. You're only changing the local copy when you execute `cat = longcat`.

That means the parameter that you passed in to this function still points to the old address which you've very inconveniently deleted.

Either pass it in as a reference or do the old C double pointer trick and pass in its address.

You may also want to ensure that the first time you call this, `cat` has a valid value and that `size` and `looong` are compatible (`looong * 2 >= size`) lest you corrupt memory.

Have a look at the following code which illustrates your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
void longcatislong1(int* cat, int &size, int &looong)
{
    int* longcat = new int[looong*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
        longcat[i] = cat[i];
    delete [] cat;
    cat = longcat;
    looong = looong * 2;
}

void longcatislong2(int*& cat, int &size, int &looong)
{
    int* longcat = new int[looong*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
        longcat[i] = cat[i];
    delete [] cat;
    cat = longcat;
    looong = looong * 2;
}

int main (void) {
    int sz = 0;
    int lng = 10;
    int *ct = 0;
    std::cout << ct << std::endl;
    longcatislong1 (ct, sz, lng);
    std::cout << ct << std::endl;
    longcatislong2 (ct, sz, lng);
    std::cout << ct << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
0
0
0x9c83060
```

meaning that the `longcatislong1` call did not successfully set `ct` on return. The `longcatislong2` function, which passes the pointer in as a reference, *does* set `ct` correctly.

---

So let's say you have a valid pointer to `0xf0000000`. When you call your original function, a new memory block is allocated, the data is copied across and the old block is deleted.

But the `ct` variable still points to the old block.

The *next* time you call the function, or even if you dereference `ct` elsewhere, you're in for a world of pain, commonly called undefined behaviour.

By making the first parameter a reference type, changes made in the function are reflected back in the variable that was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove int* cat by int** cat in function args, and then replace all cat insertions 
in function body by *cat even in cat[i] placement.

```
void longcatislong(int** cat, int &size, int &looong)
{
    int* longcat = new int[looong*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
        longcat[i] = *cat[i];
    delete [] *cat;
    *cat = longcat;
    looong = looong * 2;
}
```

And then when you call function call it like that:

```
longcatislong(&cat, size, looong);
```

Comment: You should either code in C or C++, not both at the same time :-)

Comment: C is fully compatible with C++, so why you think that pointer to pointer is not C++ construction?

Comment: @paxdiablo: implementing dynamically resized arrays yourself is not C++ anyway...

Comment: I know the language _allows_ it, @Ilay, but it's a mindset thing. C++ has `printf` as well but I don't consider people to be C++ programmers if they're still using that. The bottom line is that the reference way is a lot simpler to code and less prone to annoying little "foibles" such as having to do `*cat = ...`. And the statement "C++ is fully compatible ..." is both wrong _and_ likely to start a religious war :-)

Comment: Where did you see this in my code? I said him to use ** because I can explain it to guy who just 12 and who don't know about this construction, but I can't explain what is &* construction to beginner that's why I think that C++ and even C is not good choice when you start too lear programming. And I did not say that C++ fully campatible, just reread what I say.

Comment: You should target your answers (and read your comments) a little better. Someone who can't understand references will be unlikely to understand the concepts of double indirection. And I think you'll find the second comment on this answer has the phrase "C is fully compatible with C++". You should also learn what a smiley means at the end of a comment instead of getting so worked up.